# NameError in PaymentsController#Summary, uninitialized constant PaymentsController::SummaryPdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, nameerror

Am getting the following error

```
NameError in PaymentsController#summary
uninitialized constant PaymentsController::SummaryPdf
Extracted source (around line #133):

131        format.html {render "summary"}
132        format.pdf do
133        pdf = SummaryPdf.new(@klasses)
134        send_data pdf.render, filename: "Payments Summary_#{AcademicTerm.current.details}.pdf", type: "application/pdf"
135      end
136    end
```

`payments_controller` code is

```
def summary
  @klasses = Klass.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render "summary"}
    format.pdf do
      pdf = SummaryPdf.new(@klasses)
      send_data pdf.render, filename: "Payments Summary_#{AcademicTerm.current.details}.pdf", type: "application/pdf"
    end
```

My routes folder for payments is

```
resources :payments do
  get 'search_form', :on=>:collection
  get 'klass_menu',:on =>:collection
  get 'byklass',:on =>:collection
  get 'enrolment',:on =>:collection
  get 'bystudent',:on =>:collection
  get 'with_balance', :on=>:collection
  get 'fully_paid', :on=>:collection
  get 'all_with_balance', :on=>:collection
  get 'all_fully_paid', :on=>:collection

  get 'summary', :on=>:collection
end
```

I've tried looking through the available answers but the few who have a similar problem to mine were not answered, I'll be very glad if anyone helped.

Comment: And... What is "SummaryPdf"? Is it a class/model you created or something else? Is it included through a gem? :)

Comment: SummaryPdf is just a page responsible for printing the income summary of the payments of students in a school

Comment: A page? What do you mean by "page"? Because if you want to use it like this: SummaryPdf.new - it must be a ruby class with at least an initialize method. :)